# Plotting a heatmap for trajectory data from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap, seaborn

I have a dataframe in pandas containing information that I would like display as a heatmap of sorts. The dataframe displays the x and y co-ordinates of several objects at varying points in time and includes other information in extra columns (eg:mass).

```
          time    object   x     y     mass 

          3       1.0     216    12    12
          4       1.0     218    13    12
          5       1.0     217    12    12
          6       1.0     234    13    13
          1       2.0     361    289   23
          2       2.0     362    287   22
          3       2.0     362    286   22
          5       3.0     124    56    18
          6       3.0     126    52    17
```

I would like to create a heatmap with the x and y values corresponding to the x and y axes of the heatmap. The greater the number of objects at a particular x/y location, the more intense I would like the color to be. Any ideas on how you would accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use seaborn heatmap. First I would pivot your dataframe over your desired output, in this case `x`, `y` and say `mass`, with:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   time  object    x    y  mass
0     3     1.0  216   12    12
1     4     1.0  218   13    12
2     5     1.0  217   12    12
3     6     1.0  234   13    13
4     1     2.0  361  289    23
5     2     2.0  362  287    22
6     3     2.0  362  286    22
7     5     3.0  124   56    18
8     6     3.0  126   52    17

In [5]: d = df.pivot('x','y','mass')

In [6]: d
Out[6]: 
y     12    13    52    56    286   287   289
x                                            
124   NaN   NaN   NaN  18.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
126   NaN   NaN  17.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
216  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
217  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
218   NaN  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
234   NaN  13.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
361   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  23.0
362   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  22.0  22.0   NaN
```

Then you can apply a simple heatmap with:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(d)
```

as a result you have the following image. In the case you need more complex attribute instead of the single `mass`, you can add a new column in the original dataframe. Finally [here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) you can find some samples on how to define colormaps, style etc.

[image]

Comment: thanks - that's a great start! however I'm not interested in the mass being visualised. Is there any way of getting the heatmap to demonstrate the number of particles at the same location? Perhaps through counting?

Comment: I'm also having the problem where I can't use the x axis information as the index when pivoting, because of an error stating "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Comment: In the case of the object you can just replace mass with object in the pivot instance if it represents the number of particles you need.

Comment: In the case of duplicates entries you can use groupby to get only one to one correspondence among values and summing the number of objects I think. But it is more related on the pandas side of the problem. You should post some reproducible input with your issues so we can try to help you.